# how to update accept property in request header of form.submit in extjs

Tags: forms, extjs, http-headers, xmlhttprequest, extjs4.1

When I upload some file through extjs form.submit() my `accept` and `content type` in request header looks like this

```
Accept : application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*
Accept-Language : en-US
Content-Type : multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7df13e2a2600578
```

and in response I am getting `content type: application/json`

Now IE 11 treat response as json file and always ask to download `.json` file.

We are using REST controllers at java level.

Note: This issue cannot be reproduced on all IE 11(on some IE11 it is working fine)

I tried to change header content in extjs but no luck.

Here is my code

```
form.submit({
headers: {
    'accept':'application/json',
    'contentType': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8"
},
                url: 'http://dummyurl/abc/rest/xyz/update',
                success: function(fp, o) {
                                       .
                                       .
                                       .
```

Response:

```
{"statusCode":"200",'records':null, 'success':true, 'message':'Success'}
```

Response Header:

```
Content-encoding:gzip
Content-language:en-US
Content-type:application/json
Date:Tue, 11 Aug 2015 12:29:46 GMT
Transfer-encoding:chunked
Vary:accept-encoding
```

Can anybody please guide me how to change request header in form.submit() ?

Comment: If the issue is how the *response* is treated, why are you trying to solve it by modifying the *request* headers?

Comment: Can we override response at Java level if this is an REST api ?   I want to change 'accept' so that IE should treat response correctly

Comment: The [`Accept`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) *request* header is a message from the browser to the backend API; it may only affect the behaviour of the latter (e.g. what kind of response it sends back) — it has nothing to do with how the browser treats the response.

Comment: Oh gotcha  ! thanks Drake, but then why IE11 attempts to download it and asks user to download .json file ?

Comment: Well that is the question. I just said you were going the wrong way trying to solve it. See what response headers are there, maybe there is some weird `Content-Disposition` or something else that some IE11 treat as download.